# export 'utils' (imported as 'utils') was not found in 'ethers'

Tags: ethers.js, react, typescript

I'm trying to build a web app that can interact with blockchain, I'm using Brownie as Solidity framework and React.js. I installed [useDapp](https://usedapp-docs.netlify.app/docs) to connect with my wallet, but in the first simple usage i got the following error.

Compiled with problems:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@usedapp/core/dist/esm/src/abi/multicall/constants.js 3:29-44

export 'utils' (imported as 'utils') was not found in 'ethers' (possible exports: AbiCoder, AbstractProvider, AbstractSigner, AlchemyProvider, AnkrProvider, BaseContract, BaseWallet, Block, BrowserProvider, CloudflareProvider, ConstructorFragment, Contract, ContractEventPayload, ContractFactory, ContractTransactionReceipt, ContractTransactionResponse, EnsResolver, ErrorFragment, EtherSymbol, EtherscanProvider, EventFragment, EventLog, FallbackProvider, FeeData, FetchCancelSignal, FetchRequest, FetchResponse, FixedNumber, Fragment, FunctionFragment, HDNodeVoidWallet, HDNodeWallet, Indexed, InfuraProvider, Interface, IpcSocketProvider, JsonRpcApiProvider, JsonRpcProvider, JsonRpcSigner, LangEn, Log, LogDescription, MaxInt256, MaxUint256, MessagePrefix, MinInt256, Mnemonic, N, Network, NonceManager, ParamType, PocketProvider, QuickNodeProvider, Result, Signature, SigningKey, SocketProvider, Transaction, TransactionDescription, TransactionReceipt, TransactionResponse, Typed, TypedDataEncoder, Utf8ErrorFuncs, VoidSigner, Wallet, WebSocketProvider, WeiPerEther, Wordlist, WordlistOwl, WordlistOwlA, ZeroAddress, ZeroHash, accessListify, assert, assertArgument, assertArgumentCount, assertNormalize, assertPrivate, checkResultErrors, computeAddress, computeHmac, concat, dataLength, dataSlice, decodeBase58, decodeBase64, decodeBytes32String, decodeRlp, decryptCrowdsaleJson, decryptKeystoreJson, decryptKeystoreJsonSync, defaultPath, defineProperties, dnsEncode, encodeBase58, encodeBase64, encodeBytes32String, encodeRlp, encryptKeystoreJson, encryptKeystoreJsonSync, ensNormalize, ethers, formatEther, formatUnits, fromTwos, getAccountPath, getAddress, getBigInt, getBytes, getBytesCopy, getCreate2Address, getCreateAddress, getDefaultProvider, getIcapAddress, getNumber, getUint, hashMessage, hexlify, id, isAddress, isAddressable, isBytesLike, isCallException, isCrowdsaleJson, isError, isHexString, isKeystoreJson, isValidName, keccak256, lock, makeError, mask, namehash, parseEther, parseUnits, pbkdf2, randomBytes, recoverAddress, resolveAddress, ripemd160, scrypt, scryptSync, sha256, sha512, solidityPacked, solidityPackedKeccak256, solidityPackedSha256, stripZerosLeft, toBeArray, toBeHex, toBigInt, toNumber, toQuantity, toTwos, toUtf8Bytes, toUtf8CodePoints, toUtf8String, verifyMessage, version, zeroPadBytes, zeroPadValue)


ERROR in ./node_modules/@usedapp/core/dist/esm/src/abi/multicall2/constants.js 3:29-44

export 'utils' (imported as 'utils') was not found in 'ethers' (possible exports: AbiCoder, AbstractProvider, AbstractSigner, AlchemyProvider, AnkrProvider, BaseContract, BaseWallet, Block, BrowserProvider, CloudflareProvider, ConstructorFragment, Contract, ContractEventPayload, ContractFactory, ContractTransactionReceipt, ContractTransactionResponse, EnsResolver, ErrorFragment, EtherSymbol, EtherscanProvider, EventFragment, EventLog, FallbackProvider, FeeData, FetchCancelSignal, FetchRequest, FetchResponse, FixedNumber, Fragment, FunctionFragment, HDNodeVoidWallet, HDNodeWallet, Indexed, InfuraProvider, Interface, IpcSocketProvider, JsonRpcApiProvider, JsonRpcProvider, JsonRpcSigner, LangEn, Log, LogDescription, MaxInt256, MaxUint256, MessagePrefix, MinInt256, Mnemonic, N, Network, NonceManager, ParamType, PocketProvider, QuickNodeProvider, Result, Signature, SigningKey, SocketProvider, Transaction, TransactionDescription, TransactionReceipt, TransactionResponse, Typed, TypedDataEncoder, Utf8ErrorFuncs, VoidSigner, Wallet, WebSocketProvider, WeiPerEther, Wordlist, WordlistOwl, WordlistOwlA, ZeroAddress, ZeroHash, accessListify, assert, assertArgument, assertArgumentCount, assertNormalize, assertPrivate, checkResultErrors, computeAddress, computeHmac, concat, dataLength, dataSlice, decodeBase58, decodeBase64, decodeBytes32String, decodeRlp, decryptCrowdsaleJson, decryptKeystoreJson, decryptKeystoreJsonSync, defaultPath, defineProperties, dnsEncode, encodeBase58, encodeBase64, encodeBytes32String, encodeRlp, encryptKeystoreJson, encryptKeystoreJsonSync, ensNormalize, ethers, formatEther, formatUnits, fromTwos, getAccountPath, getAddress, getBigInt, getBytes, getBytesCopy, getCreate2Address, getCreateAddress, getDefaultProvider, getIcapAddress, getNumber, getUint, hashMessage, hexlify, id, isAddress, isAddressable, isBytesLike, isCallException, isCrowdsaleJson, isError, isHexString, isKeystoreJson, isValidName, keccak256, lock, makeError, mask, namehash, parseEther, parseUnits, pbkdf2, randomBytes, recoverAddress, resolveAddress, ripemd160, scrypt, scryptSync, sha256, sha512, solidityPacked, solidityPackedKeccak256, solidityPackedSha256, stripZerosLeft, toBeArray, toBeHex, toBigInt, toNumber, toQuantity, toTwos, toUtf8Bytes, toUtf8CodePoints, toUtf8String, verifyMessage, version, zeroPadBytes, zeroPadValue)


ERROR in ./node_modules/@usedapp/core/dist/esm/src/constants/abi/index.js 7:18-33

export 'utils' (imported as 'utils') was not found in 'ethers' (possible exports: AbiCoder, AbstractProvider, AbstractSigner, AlchemyProvider, AnkrProvider, BaseContract, BaseWallet, Block, BrowserProvider, CloudflareProvider, ConstructorFragment, Contract, ContractEventPayload, ContractFactory, ContractTransactionReceipt, ContractTransactionResponse, EnsResolver, ErrorFragment, EtherSymbol, EtherscanProvider, EventFragment, EventLog, FallbackProvider, FeeData, FetchCancelSignal, FetchRequest, FetchResponse, FixedNumber, Fragment, FunctionFragment, HDNodeVoidWallet, HDNodeWallet, Indexed, InfuraProvider, Interface, IpcSocketProvider, JsonRpcApiProvider, JsonRpcProvider, JsonRpcSigner, LangEn, Log, LogDescription, MaxInt256, MaxUint256, MessagePrefix, MinInt256, Mnemonic, N, Network, NonceManager, ParamType, PocketProvider, QuickNodeProvider, Result, Signature, SigningKey, SocketProvider, Transaction, TransactionDescription, TransactionReceipt, TransactionResponse, Typed, TypedDataEncoder, Utf8ErrorFuncs, VoidSigner, Wallet, WebSocketProvider, WeiPerEther, Wordlist, WordlistOwl, WordlistOwlA, ZeroAddress, ZeroHash, accessListify, assert, assertArgument, assertArgumentCount, assertNormalize, assertPrivate, checkResultErrors, computeAddress, computeHmac, concat, dataLength, dataSlice, decodeBase58, decodeBase64, decodeBytes32String, decodeRlp, decryptCrowdsaleJson, decryptKeystoreJson, decryptKeystoreJsonSync, defaultPath, defineProperties, dnsEncode, encodeBase58, encodeBase64, encodeBytes32String, encodeRlp, encryptKeystoreJson, encryptKeystoreJsonSync, ensNormalize, ethers, formatEther, formatUnits, fromTwos, getAccountPath, getAddress, getBigInt, getBytes, getBytesCopy, getCreate2Address, getCreateAddress, getDefaultProvider, getIcapAddress, getNumber, getUint, hashMessage, hexlify, id, isAddress, isAddressable, isBytesLike, isCallException, isCrowdsaleJson, isError, isHexString, isKeystoreJson, isValidName, keccak256, lock, makeError, mask, namehash, parseEther, parseUnits, pbkdf2, randomBytes, recoverAddress, resolveAddress, ripemd160, scrypt, scryptSync, sha256, sha512, solidityPacked, solidityPackedKeccak256, solidityPackedSha256, stripZerosLeft, toBeArray, toBeHex, toBigInt, toNumber, toQuantity, toTwos, toUtf8Bytes, toUtf8CodePoints, toUtf8String, verifyMessage, version, zeroPadBytes, zeroPadValue)


ERROR in ./node_modules/@usedapp/core/dist/esm/src/helpers/address.js 9:29-45

export 'utils' (imported as 'utils') was not found in 'ethers' (possible exports: AbiCoder, AbstractProvider, AbstractSigner, AlchemyProvider, AnkrProvider, BaseContract, BaseWallet, Block, BrowserProvider, CloudflareProvider, ConstructorFragment, Contract, ContractEventPayload, ContractFactory, ContractTransactionReceipt, ContractTransactionResponse, EnsResolver, ErrorFragment, EtherSymbol, EtherscanProvider, EventFragment, EventLog, FallbackProvider, FeeData, FetchCancelSignal, FetchRequest, FetchResponse, FixedNumber, Fragment, FunctionFragment, HDNodeVoidWallet, HDNodeWallet, Indexed, InfuraProvider, Interface, IpcSocketProvider, JsonRpcApiProvider, JsonRpcProvider, JsonRpcSigner, LangEn, Log, LogDescription, MaxInt256, MaxUint256, MessagePrefix, MinInt256, Mnemonic, N, Network, NonceManager, ParamType, PocketProvider, QuickNodeProvider, Result, Signature, SigningKey, SocketProvider, Transaction, TransactionDescription, TransactionReceipt, TransactionResponse, Typed, TypedDataEncoder, Utf8ErrorFuncs, VoidSigner, Wallet, WebSocketProvider, WeiPerEther, Wordlist, WordlistOwl, WordlistOwlA, ZeroAddress, ZeroHash, accessListify, assert, assertArgument, assertArgumentCount, assertNormalize, assertPrivate, checkResultErrors, computeAddress, computeHmac, concat, dataLength, dataSlice, decodeBase58, decodeBase64, decodeBytes32String, decodeRlp, decryptCrowdsaleJson, decryptKeystoreJson, decryptKeystoreJsonSync, defaultPath, defineProperties, dnsEncode, encodeBase58, encodeBase64, encodeBytes32String, encodeRlp, encryptKeystoreJson, encryptKeystoreJsonSync, ensNormalize, ethers, formatEther, formatUnits, fromTwos, getAccountPath, getAddress, getBigInt, getBytes, getBytesCopy, getCreate2Address, getCreateAddress, getDefaultProvider, getIcapAddress, getNumber, getUint, hashMessage, hexlify, id, isAddress, isAddressable, isBytesLike, isCallException, isCrowdsaleJson, isError, isHexString, isKeystoreJson, isValidName, keccak256, lock, makeError, mask, namehash, parseEther, parseUnits, pbkdf2, randomBytes, recoverAddress, resolveAddress, ripemd160, scrypt, scryptSync, sha256, sha512, solidityPacked, solidityPackedKeccak256, solidityPackedSha256, stripZerosLeft, toBeArray, toBeHex, toBigInt, toNumber, toQuantity, toTwos, toUtf8Bytes, toUtf8CodePoints, toUtf8String, verifyMessage, version, zeroPadBytes, zeroPadValue)
```

here is my App.tsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { DAppProvider, ChainId } from "@usedapp/core";


function App() {
  return (
    <DAppProvider config={{ supportedChains: [ChainId.Goerli] }}>
      <div>
        Hello!
      </div>
    </DAppProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

please any suggestions to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://workspace.web3client.app/evm?web3ClientToken=50f4540e-e813-48a0-8cac-e2bd762a86ea

And import / create your abi and execute it.

It hase code generate option <> to generate code for you which can be used easily in your project.